# Security Web programming API in Python

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, api

Is there a secure API available which will help protect against attacks like XSS, CSRF etc by providing encoders, token support etc.? for python which can be used with google app engine?

I do not want to reinvent the wheel by coding it all again if its already out there .

Answer (score 5):

[Python Security](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/) is a good resource:

- [Access Control/Authorization](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/accesscontrol/)
- [Authentication](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/authentication/)
- [Configuration](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/configuration/)
- [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/cross-siterequestforgery/)
- [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/cross-sitescripting/)
- [Cryptography](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/cryptography/)
- [Escaping](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/escaping/)
- [Hashing](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/hashing/)
- [Injection](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/injection/)
- [Object Reference](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/objectreference/)
- [Redirects](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/redirects/)
- [Session Management](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/sessionmanagement/)
- [Taint Mode](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/taintmode/)
- [Transport Layer Security](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/transportlayersecurity/)
- [Validation](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/validation/)